# Changing background colour of cells in ListView?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am trying to change the colour of each cell in the listview depending on the text in it. This is how I am currently populating the listview:

```
    DBHelper db = new DBHelper(this);
    List<HiveEquipment> heList = db.getEquipmentForHive(currentHiveId);
    final ArrayAdapter<HiveEquipment> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<HiveEquipment>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, heList);
    final ListView equipmentList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            equipmentList.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
        }
    });
```

So I am just trying some things out, I have tried to change the background colour using:

list.getChildAt(0).setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);

And this returned a null pointer. So I checked the child count using:

Log.d("Test",""+equipmentList.getChildCount());

But this is returning 0 even though it is displaying one item in my listview.

Could anyone help me understand why this is returning 0, and how I would go about selecting each cell to change the background colour?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure the listView is populated (shown in UI) before accessing the child view object. This means that each child item views are created. In your case i believe your are trying to get the child immediately after setting the adapter to listView, that is why the getChildAt is returning null.

So with your approach, Execute the below code only after the list view is created.

```
View listViewChildAt = listView.getChildAt(0);
listViewChildAt.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
```

**Other best way is to create a custom Adapter and set the color for the required child view in getView**

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View contentView , ViewGroup parent)
{
    String text = getItem(position);

    View row = mContext.getLayoutInflater().inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, null);
    if(text.equalsIgnoreCase("yourText")){
        row.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
    }
    return row;
}
```